# rails 4 specify gems for development, testing and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2

I deployed the app on heroku as testing and amazon as production. On the testing and development(local), I used postgresql and on Amazon EC2 I used Mysql. So I want the pg gem only loaded on testing and development and mysql2 gem loaded on production.

What is the best practice to work around with the problem?

Thanks

Comment: By 'loaded on' do you mean loaded into memory and used, or simply installed?

Comment: @PinnyM sorry i meant loaded into memory and used

Comment: Then @mind.blank's answer should work for you.

Comment: Yeah. Your answer covers more, so I accept yours although @mind.blank's also helps. thx all, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use the same dbms for development, testing, and production.  But I doubt that's what you wanted to hear...

In any event, bundler doesn't support this scenario.  That is, you can't simply tell it to not install certain gems in a given environment - even if they won't be used.  You can tell it to not load up certain gems by declaring them in a `group` block (as @mind.blank proposed), but they will still be installed. You can, however, use simple ruby constructs, namely `if-else` or `case` blocks, to only run certain code (and load/install certain gems) given a specific condition.

The problem with this is that your Gemfile.lock file will be out of sync across your deployments - which is not what bundler (or Capistrano) expects.  But there are flags you can use to tell your deployment to ignore the Gemfile.lock file and `bundle install` based on it's reading of the Gemfile if you really want to...

Answer (score 1):

Does the Gemfile behave differently in Rails 3.2 and Rails 4?
If not then you can specify which gem should be loaded in which environment:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "pg"
end

group :production do
  gem "mysql2"
end
```

Comment: This won't load up the unneeded gem at runtime, but it will install it.

Comment: @PinnyM oh I see, I've changed loaded to installed. If this isn't what the OP is looking for I'll delete the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure myself what the OP means, waiting for clarification... ;)  But you had it right the first time.  It will be installed regardless, but only loaded within the group environment specified.